# combineLatest cancels http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have added searchCustomer code, but it is just normal get request from dotnet back-end. I don't have any problem with getting response from static JSON or static values to pretend the result from back-end, but it behaves differently when I get response from dotnet back-end.

I changed the way to get an array of observables.

```
list$!: Observable<any>;
result: any[] = [];

this.list$ = this.ctl.valueChanges
  .pipe(       
    debounceTime(100),
    startWith(null),
    mergeMap((res: any) => {
      this.result = [];
      this.keyword = res;
      return this.dataService.searchCustomer(this.keyword);
    }),
    switchMap((res: any) =>
    {
      this.result.push(res);
      return this.dataService.searchItem(this.keyword);
    }),
    switchMap((res: any) => {
      this.result.push(res);
     return this.dataService.searchTask(this.keyword);
    }),
    switchMap((res: any) => {
      this.result.push(res);
      return of(this.result);
    }),
    catchError(err => of([]))

  );
```

I created a search bar to input a keyword and call multiple HTTP requests and combine to one. I use combineLatest, but only the first request gets a response and the other requests are cancelled.

[image]

DataService returns just normal HTTP request from dotnet back-end.

```
searchCustomer(input: string) {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('input', input);
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${ApiPaths.Main}SearchCustomer`, {params});
    }


this.list$ = this.ctl.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  startWith(null),
  mergeMap((res: any) => {
    if (res) {
      this.keyword = res;
      return combineLatest([
        this.dataService.searchCustomer(res),
        this.dataService.searchItem(res),
        this.dataService.searchTask(res),
      ]).pipe(map(([a, ...b]) => a.concat(...b)));
    } else {
      return of([]);
    }
  })
);
```

And html is

```
<input  type="text" placeholder="Enter title" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="ctl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of list$ | async ; let i = index">
    <mat-option>
      {{option.id}}-{{option.summary}}
    </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

How can I make it wait for all requests completed? I tried forkJoin but same.

Comment: What you have seems fine, so there's something that unsubscribes the chain. I'm suspicious it could be related to changing `keyword` but I could be wrong. It's hard to give any advice without a reproducible demo.

Comment: Can you create the issue in StackBlitz? I tested your code with `forkJoin` but it seems not able to reproduce. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pys4bh?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: You should also share the code of `dataService`

Comment: You could also have an interceptor messing things up.